# get only last mobile number entered/edited for each contact id in phonebook

Tags: android

I am using this code to get phone contacts. I am getting multiple names based on how many mobile/work numbers I have entered . I basically want only one contact id with last edited/added mobile number .Is there a way I can edit the following query to  achieve that result ? I really appreciate any help.

```
   Cursor cur = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", null,
                    ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");


        int number = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        int name = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME);



        while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String phName = mCursor.getString(name);
            String phNumber = mCursor.getString(number);

            String thumbnailUri = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));

}
```

Comment: try using the modified date   Cursor cur = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", null,
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP + " ASC");

Comment: How can I use that. I have updated my code in Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the modified date

```
Cursor cur = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", null, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP + " DESC");

    int _id = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID);
    int number = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
    int name = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME);



    while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = mCursor.getString(_id);
        String phName = mCursor.getString(name);
        String phNumber = mCursor.getString(number);

        String thumbnailUri = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));

    }
```

check you queue. If your id are same for similar name contacts then group them. Let me know after trying this

Comment: I am sorry if you did not get my Q properly. I am getting same name multiple times with different mobile number .I would like to get only 1 which was entered/edited last .

Comment: query for _ID instead

Comment: Please can you modify the above query w.r.t your comment. It would be very helpful.

Comment: Close Enough. Thanks.